# Unable to configure ASP.NET for Azure Access Token

Tags: reactjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt, azure-ad-msal

I was hoping that someone might be able to shed some light on issues that I'm having with authentication. I've mostly used this guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-overview

I've got a react app that is successfully (I think...) retrieving access tokens for my API:

```
  const account = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
  if (account) {
    msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
      ...apiToken,
      account: account
    }).then((response) => {
      setToken(response.accessToken);
    });
  }
```

My requests place the token in the authorization header:
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFpHl.png)

My token looks looks like: [Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC8Iu.png)

[API Registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH96U.png)

My API returns 401 whenever I use the Authorize attribute. Because my client is retrieving a token that looks correct, I'm assuming the issue is on my API. This is what I have in my startup auth:

```
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(
                new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // Check if the audience is intended to be this application
                    ValidAudiences = new[] { [MY_API_CLIENT_ID (SAME AS AUDIENCE IN TOKEN)], [MY API REGISTRATION URI] },

                    // Change below to 'true' if you want this Web API to accept tokens issued to one Azure AD tenant only (single-tenant)
                    // Note that this is a simplification for the quickstart here. You should validate the issuer. For details, 
                    // see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateTokenReplay = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = false,
                    ValidateActor = false, //all false for testing
                },
                new OpenIdConnectSecurityKeyProvider("https://login.microsoftonline.com/[MY_TENANT_ID]/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration")
            ),
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tough silent error here. I noticed that none of the validation callbacks were being invoked. I was missing the package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb